# getting Error preprocess.py [options] <name> <in_dir> <out_dir> python

Tags: python, pytorch, preprocessor

I have some problem
can you tell me how to resolve this error **usage: preprocess.py [options]  <in_dir> <out_dir>**

I am working on this https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17TMYl3anIwegk-sBU6jHngpqo_3sjtW8#scrollTo=f_xjMkeizPYI

deepvoice3_pytorch https://github.com/r9y9/deepvoice3_pytorch

I download my dataset from https://keithito.com/LJ-Speech-Dataset/

there are 3 things in dataset But when I unzip my dataset

- WAVs folder of audio
- redme file
- metadat.csv

There is no dataset.json file there is a CSV file is both work same or how?
So how I can run this

```
!mv -v ./datasets/dataset.json ./datasets/audio/dataset.json
```

getting **Error** : No such file or directory

When I run this in colab

```
#!rm -rf preprocessed
!mkdir preprocessed
!python preprocess.py json_meta \
                      "./datasets/audio/dataset.json" \
                      "./preprocessed" \
                      --preset=presets/20180505_deepvoice3_ljspeech.json \
                      --hparams="sample_rate=48000"
```

there is an **Error** usage: preprocess.py [options]  <in_dir> <out_dir>